# Converting Framework to a Library

Tags: iphone, frameworks, ios, yaml

I want to use the framework found at the link below within an iOS app. I have it working within the simulator but after some digging it looks like you are unable to use frameworks on devices and especially when distributing through the App Store. Please correct me if I am wrong.

https://github.com/mirek/YAML.framework/

How would I go about converting this framework to a library? I have looked at simply dragging the files from the framework to the app which doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/Ecarrion/YAML.IOS
Just grab the YAML.Framework folder

And you actually can use framework, you just can't use dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It's super easy.

Give the general iOS static framework structure:

```
3rdPartyLib.framework
   |---3rdPartyLib -> Versions/Current/3rdPartyLib
   |---Headers
   |---Resources
         |---Info.plist
         |---SomeBundle.bundle
   |---Versions
         |---A
         |---Current -> ./A
```

You have to

1) Copy the static library file in a new folder

```
3rdPartyLib.framework/Versions/Current/3rdPartyLib
```

2) Rename is with .a extension and copy to a new folder

```
3rdPartyLib/
   |---3rdPartyLib.a
```

3) Copy all the headers in the folder

```
3rdPartyLib.framework/Headers
```

in a new headers folder in the new folder

```
3rdPartyLib/
   |---Headers/
```

At this point you should end up with

```
3rdPartyLib/
       |---3rdPartyLib.a
       |---Headers/
```

This is your static library that you can use within your app or within another iOS framework to be distributed to other apps.