# How to split functionality into separate apps iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on an app that serves two different types of user. Both users have some common functionalities.

One group is the general public, who uses the app to navigate basic events or request for new events.

The second group is who can provide services to the general public (can be paid or unpaid). They primarily access the profiles created by general users. They can add details, e.g. notes about conversations with them.

Now we want to divide both the users because the app is getting quite large and at any time user can be part of one group only.

How can I create separate apps?

1. Using different targets for each group is it a better solution? I tried this but it is not helping us to reduce app size.
2. Creating separate project will make maintaining challenge because both uses have some common functionalities.

Comment: Have you thought of creating a Framework of the "basic" funcitonality? And the extended App could include and enhance the framework with premium viewcontrollers etc.?

Comment: Nope, @Lepidopteron I don't know to create a Framework in iOS? If you have any content related to creating a Framework then plz share.

Comment: Well, I havent tried it with an entire application yet. Of course you would end up with 3 projects. One: the framework with almost all functions. 2nd: The "light" app - taking care of standard app icon stuff, Info.plist and including the framework. 3rd: The premium one including the Framework and a lot of new controllers. There are two sources for how to do so: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework and here is the basic structure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26863796/464016

Comment: @Lepidopteron Thanks, i will try this.